# Coriolis force effect on spiral galaxies

Tags: galaxies, coriolis-effect

I know the Coriolis force 
[explains](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/370/11019) 
the counterclockwise rotation of the hurricanes hitting the U.S.
I wonder if a Coriolis effect also determines 
(or at least influences) the direction of rotation of spiral galaxies?

Comment: You mean, considering galaxies in a rotating galaxy cluster, how much of an influence has the Coriolis force? Interesting question… I mean, that there would be a Coriolis force goes without saying but as to its significance, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The Coriolis force is applied when matter changes radius without changing speed.

That's relevant to air movement constrained to the surface of a more or less spherical earth.

The matter in galaxies is not similarly constrained, and can move freely, consequently (unless acted on in some way) it remains in an orbit corresponding to its velocity.

Comment: Thanks. Is not the matter in galaxies acted on by gravity, perhaps from a nearby massive galaxy or cluster or ...?